# Is there any document/record level security in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I am new to couchbase and NoSql.We have a central/main data center that contains whole documents and several branches/offices, they will have their own specific documents.We want to replicate some documents between branches and main data center.

Each branch must see its own documents and not others. 
I want to know if there is any document level security in couchbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you decided what mechanism you are going to use for replication yet? If you use Couchbase's included XDCR (Cross Data Centre Replication) you could use XDCR filtering to replicate only a subset of documents from the main data centre to the branches. In this way the branch servers will only have the specific documents you send to them. You could also send any updates on the data back to the main DC by setting up a second XDCR process **from** the branch back to the main DC.

Couchbase's [XDCR filtering documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-filtering.html) explain the filtering setup quite well and [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-overview.html) are some more details about the XDCR setup in general. Hope that helps!